# Why does my neural network have extremely low weights after a few epochs?

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

I just started to learn about neural network and this is my first one. The problem is that the more data I have, the lower the weight become after 2-3 epochs which is unusual and this cause my NN to learn nothing.

**To repodruce**
In DataSet class, search for function CreateData and change nbofexample to something like 20, you'll see if you print the weights that they are in a normal range (evenly spaced between -1 and 1) but then if you set the nbofexample to something like 200, then after only 2 or 3 epochs, most of the weigths of the last layer will be extremely close from 0 and they will stay in that zone for the rest of the training. Obviously, this cause the NN to fail.

By the way, my NN is basically analyzing arrays of number between 0 and 9 divided by 10 as a normalization to check if the array is sorted. In the code below I put a lot of comments the code can be easily understand.

There's is probably an easy fix but I just don't get it :(

Here is the complete code if you want try it: (it's in python btw)

```
import numpy as np
import time
import random
import time

#This class is only used for creating the data if needed
class DataSet():
    
    #check if sorted
    def checkPossibility(A):
        return sorted(A) == A

    #will be used later for more complex problems (taken from the faster answer of a coding challenge on LeetCode)
    #def checkPossibility(A):
    #    p = None
    #    for i in range(len(A) - 1):
    #        if A[i] > A[i+1]:
    #            if p is not None:
    #                return False
    #            p = i
    #    return (p is None or p == 0 or p == len(A)-2 or
    #            A[p-1] <= A[p+1] or A[p] <= A[p+2])
    

    #returns inputs and outputs using my poorly written algorithm
    def CreateData():
        
        #settings
        nbofchar=4
        nbofexample=200
        
        #initialize arrays
        inputs = [0]*nbofchar;
        output = [1]
        
        #handling dumbness
        if nbofexample>pow(10,nbofchar): 
            print("Too much data... resizing to max data")
            nbofexample=pow(10,nbofchar)
        elif nbofexample==0:
            print("You need examples to train! (Error nbofexample==0)")
        
        #if there is more than half of the max possible example being request, then create all possible examples and delete randomly until it's the requested size
        if nbofexample>pow(10,nbofchar)/2:
            
            #creating all possible examples
            for i in range(1,pow(10,nbofchar)): 
                new_ex = [int(a) for a in str(i)]
                while len(new_ex)<nbofchar:
                    new_ex=[0]+new_ex
                inputs = np.vstack((inputs,np.dot(new_ex,1/10)))  #normalization /10 so the value is between 0 and 1 ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
                output = np.vstack((output,[int(DataSet.checkPossibility(new_ex))]))
            
            #deleting     
            while len(inputs)>nbofexample:
                index = random.randint(0,len(inputs)-1)
                inputs = np.delete(inputs,index)
                output = np.delete(output,index)

            return inputs, output
        
        #if there is less than half (or half) then, create example randomly until it's the requested size
        else:
            i=1
            while i < nbofexample: 
                new_ex = [random.randint(0,9) for a in range(nbofchar)]
                if sum(np.any(inputs)==new_ex)==0:
                    i+=1
                    inputs = np.vstack((inputs,np.dot(new_ex,1/10)))    #normalization /10 so the value is between 0 and 1 ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
                    output = np.vstack((output,[int(DataSet.checkPossibility(new_ex))]))
            return inputs, output

#assigning weights to each layer
class NeuLayer():
    def __init__(self, nbofneuron, inputsperneuron):
        self.weight = 2 * np.random.random((inputsperneuron,nbofneuron))-1

#the actual neural network
class NeuNet():    

        def __init__(self, layers):
            self.layers = layers

        def _sigmoid(self, x):
            k = 1
            return 1 / (1+np.exp(-x/k))

        def _sigmoid_derivative(self, x):
            return x * (1-x)

        def train(self, training_set_inputs, training_set_outputs, nboftime):

            #debug
            timer1 = 0


            if len(self.layers)<2: return

            for iteration in range(nboftime):
                
                delta = [0] * len(self.layers)
                error = [0] * len(self.layers)
                outputlayers = self.think(training_set_inputs)
                
                #find deltas for each layer "i" (to be able to properly change weights)
                for i in range(len(self.layers)-1,-1,-1):
                    if i==len(self.layers)-1:
                        error[i] = training_set_outputs - outputlayers[i]                      
                    else:
                        error[i] = np.dot(delta[i+1],self.layers[i+1].weight.T)
                    delta[i] = error[i] * self._sigmoid_derivative(outputlayers[i])              


                #assign weigths for each layer "i"
                for i in range(len(self.layers)):
                   if i==0:
                       self.layers[0].weight += np.dot(training_set_inputs.T,delta[0])
                   else:
                       self.layers[i].weight += np.dot(outputlayers[i-1].T,delta[i])

                #display progression and the test result
                if Display_progression: 
                    if timer1<time.time():
                        timer1=time.time()+delay
                        value = ((iteration+1)/nboftime)*100
                        test_input = np.array([.1,.2,.1,.1])
                        print('%.2f'%value+"%     test_input = " + str(test_input) + "     test_output = "+ str(self.think(test_input)[-1]))

        #return output of each layer from an input
        def think(self, input):
            outforlayers = [None]*len(self.layers)
            outforlayer = input
            for i in range(len(self.layers)):
                outforlayer = self._sigmoid(np.dot(outforlayer, self.layers[i].weight))
                outforlayers[i] = outforlayer
            return outforlayers

#datamaker
creating_data=True
train = True

if creating_data:
    
    #creates files with inputs and their expected output
    print("Start creating data...")
    input, output = DataSet.CreateData();
    print("Data created!")
    file = open("data_input","wb")
    np.save(file, input)
    file.close;
    file = open("data_output","wb")
    np.save(file, output)
    file.close;

if train:

    default_data_set=False

    if default_data_set:
        #default training set
        inp_training = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0], [0.1, 0.1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0], [0.1, 0, 0.1, 0, 0], [0, 0.1, 0.1, 0, 0], [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0, 0],
                             [0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0], [0.1, 0, 0, 0.1, 0], [0, 0.1, 0, 0.1, 0], [0.1, 0.1, 0, 0.1, 0], [0, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 0], [0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 0], [0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0], [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0],
                             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1], [0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0.1], [0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0.1], [0.1, 0.1, 0, 0, 0.1], [0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0.1], [0.1, 0, 0.1, 0, 0.1], [0, 0.1, 0.1, 0, 0.1], [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0, 0.1],
                             [0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.1], [0.1, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.1], [0, 0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.1], [0.1, 0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.1], [0, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1], [0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1], [0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1], [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]])
        out_training = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
                             0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,
                             0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,
                             0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]).T

    else:
        print("Loading data files...")
        file = open("data_input","rb")
        inp_training = np.load(file)
        file.close;
        file = open("data_output","rb")
        out_training = np.load(file)
        file.close;
        print("Done reading from data files!")


    #debug
    Display_progression = True;
    delay = 1   #seconds

    #initialize
    np.random.seed(5)
    netlayer_input = NeuLayer(10,len(inp_training[0]))
    netlayer2 = NeuLayer(10,10)
    netlayer3 = NeuLayer(10,10)
    netlayer4 = NeuLayer(10,10)
    netlayer_out = NeuLayer(len(out_training[0]),10)
    All_layers = [netlayer_input,netlayer2,netlayer3,netlayer4,netlayer_out]
    brain = NeuNet(All_layers)

    #train
    print("Start training...")
    brain.train(inp_training, out_training, 100000)
    print("Done!")


    #final test
    outputfinal = brain.think(np.array([0,.1,.3,.7]))


    #output
    a = outputfinal[-1] #[-1] so we get the last layer's output(s)
    print(a)
```

**Note**
This is my first time asking a question on stackoverflow so tell me if I'm missing crucial information for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neural Networks can suffer from something known as the [Vanishing Gradient Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_gradient_problem), caused by the more classical activations like Sigmoid or Tanh.

In laymen terms, basically activations like Sigmoid and Tanh really squeeze the inputs, right? For example, sigmoid(10) and sigmoid(100) are .9999 and 1 respectively. Even though the inputs have changed so much, the outputs have barely changed -  the function is effectively constant at this point. And where a function is almost constant, its derivative tends to zero (or a very small value). These very small derivatives/gradients multiply with each other and become effectively zero, preventing your model from learning anything at all - your weights get stuck and stop updating.

I suggest you do some further reading on this topic at your own time. Among several solutions, one way to solve this is to use a different activation, like [ReLU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)).